# Given $X \in [2, 3]$, and $XY = 1$, solve the range of $E(X)E(Y)$?

Tags: inequality, expectation, covariance

This is equivalent to ask $cov(X, 1/X)$ when $X \in[2, 3]$.

Can you do this with some clever method?

Edit: clearly $E(X)E(Y) = E(XY) - cov(X,Y) = 1 - cov(X,Y) = 1- cov(X, 1/X)$,

clearly, $X$ and $\frac{1}{X}$ will move in opposite direction, so $cov(X, 1/X) \le 0$,

thus the minimum of $E(X)E(Y)$ will be 1. But how to get the maximum?

My guess is that for example, $X$ could be 50% equals to 2, and 50% equals to 3, $E(X) = 2.5$.

thus $1/X$ will half time 1/2, half time 1/3. $E(1/X) = 5/12$;

Thus it's easy to get $E(X)E(Y) = 25/24$. But is this the maximum? Seems to be by instinct. But how do you proove it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. It is advisable to learn MathJax typesetting as it will increase the chances to get positive responses. Also to show any own attempts in trying to solve the problems can increase the chance for positive responses.

Comment: @mathreadler, thanks, I just edited. Could this be upvoted back? :D

Comment: For the lower bound, I would use Jensen's inequality: $$E[X]E[1/X]\geq E[X] \frac{1}{E[X]} = 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum is indeed $25/24$.

We want to maximize $E[X]E[1/X]$ over all random variables $X$ that take values in the interval $[2,3]$.

1. Fact 1:  We have
   $$ (1/x) + (1/6)x \leq 5/6 \quad \forall x \in [2,3]$$
   with equality when $x \in \{2,3\}$.
2. Fact 2: Fix $m \in [2,3]$.  To maximize $E[1/X]$ over all random variables $X$ that take values in $[2,3]$ and that satisfy $E[X]=m$, we take the random variable $X^*$ that satisfies
   $$P[X^*=2]=p, P[X^*=3]=1-p$$
   where $p$ is the value in $[0,1]$ that satisfies
   $$m=2p+3(1-p)$$
   Proof: Let $X$ be a random variable that takes values in $[2,3]$ and has mean $m$.   Then we have by Fact 1:
   $$ (1/X) + (1/6) X \leq 5/6 =  (1/X^*) + (1/6)X^*$$
   Taking expectations of the above gives:
   $$ E[1/X] + (1/6) E[X] \leq E[1/X^*] + (1/6)E[X^*]$$
   Since we know $E[X]=E[X^*]$ we obtain:
   $$ E[1/X]\leq E[1/X^*] \quad \Box$$
3. By Fact 2, it suffices to maximize $E[X]E[1/X]$ over all random variables of the type $X^*$ that satisfy $P[X^*=2]=p, P[X^*=3]=1-p$. So
   $$E[X^*]E[1/X^*] = (2p + 3(1-p))((1/2)p + (1/3)(1-p))$$
   This is a quadratic equation in $p$ that is maximized at $p^*=1/2$, from which we obtain
   $$ E[X^*]E[1/X^*]=25/24$$

Comment: Nice. Fact 1 is also by convexity, so more generally for a convex function f, the max of E[f(X)]/f(E[X]) in [a,b] is achieved by maximizing (mx+c)/f(x) in [a,b], where y=mx+c is the line joining (a,f(a)) and (b,f(b)). Another nice thing from the proof is the tightness being at the two-point distribution; all these arguments work identically if we wanted to maximize, say, E[f(X)]-f(E(X)] in an interval, eg: variance.